# Calculating median of a sorted array using Quicksort, Quickselect method and Selection Sort Python

Tags: python, coding-style

**I solved that using Quickselect algorithm. Now i want to implement this using Quicksort and Selection sort algorithm.**

Comment: Can you include more information about what the issue is here and what you've tried so far. Also as far as I can tell, the sorting algorithm should not impact the median or how to get the median. Median is always the middle element (or average of two middle elements) of a sorted array, so the algorithm you used to sort the array is irrelevant.

Comment: I know the Median is always the middle element and I can easily find it using module but i want find the median using this two algorithm. 1)Quicksort , 2) Selection Sort

Comment: Yes I have attached below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, all you want is two implementations of sorting and applying median?

```
def selection_sort(arr):
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        smallest_ind = i
        for j in range(i + 1, len(arr)):
            if arr[j] < arr[smallest_ind]:
                smallest_ind = j
        arr[i], arr[smallest_ind] = arr[smallest_ind], arr[i]

def quick_sort(arr):
    if len(arr) <= 1:
       return arr
    pivot = arr[0]
    i = 0
    for j in range(len(arr)-1):
        if arr[j+1] < pivot:
           arr[j+1],arr[i+1] = arr[i+1],arr[j+1]
           i += 1
    arr[0],arr[i] = arr[i],arr[0]
    left = quick_sort(arr[:i])
    right = quick_sort(arr[i+1:])
    left.append(arr[i])
    return left + right

def median(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    return (arr[n//2] + arr[(n-1)//2]) / 2
```

Now test the functions:

```
nums = [5, 8, 4, 1, 2, 5]
quick_sorted = quick_sort(nums)
selection_sorted = nums.copy()
selection_sort(selection_sorted)

median_quicksort = median(quick_sorted)
median_selection_sort = median(selection_sorted)
```

Both of them give the expected result `4.5`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#implementation with a randomly chosen pivot

import random

def select_nth(n, items):
    pivot = random.choice(items)

    lesser = [item for item in items if item < pivot]
    if len(lesser) > n:
        return select_nth(n, lesser)
    n -= len(lesser)

    numequal = items.count(pivot)
    if numequal > n:
        return pivot
    n -= numequal

    greater = [item for item in items if item > pivot]
    return select_nth(n, greater)

#now trivially turns this into a methods to finds medians

def median(items):
    if len(items) % 2:
        return select_nth(len(items)//2, items)

    else:
        left  = select_nth((len(items)-1) // 2, items)
        right = select_nth((len(items)+1) // 2, items)

        return (left + right) / 2
```